# How does istream::ignore( ) work?

Tags: c++

I've been reading about istream::ignore( ) [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/). I think I get the main idea of the function it does, but I've seen some examples of [accepting only numeric input](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) that uses this function, and I'm not sure why it works.

Why would this code ignore everything except numeric input?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    std::istringstream input("1\n"
                             "some non-numeric input\n"
                             "2\n");
    for(;;) {
        int n;
        input >> n;

        if (input.eof() || input.bad()) {
            break;
        } else if (input.fail()) {
            input.clear(); // unset failbit
            input.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // skip bad input
        } else {
            std::cout << n << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

I had thought that istream::ignore( ) would ignore any and all characters specified by a certain number until the delimiter..

Comment: Well, it does ignore all characters until it finds `'\n'`.

Comment: Your last sentence describes it. It ignores as many characters as it's told to, or until it finds the delimiter. You're passing in a number and a delimiter.

Comment: The example I linked says that it skips over non-numeric input..so that description is wrong?

Comment: @ChrisHarris, I presume it means that if there are numeric characters at the beginning, they'll be read by `input >> n;`, so otherwise, `ignore()` would do its thing, as well as when it reads any characters it can't extract after the initial number.

Comment: @ChrisHarris: `input >> n;` will read a number and parse all characters that do not match a digit. Starting from the first character that is not a digit, `ignore` will skipping everything until it finds `'\n'`. So if a digit is present between the last digit and the `\n`, I guess it will be skipped.

Comment: @ChrisHarris - the eample does not do what you think the linked-to page said. Precisely, this example skips from the first non-numeric, non-whitespace character on any line to the end of the that line. Consider what it does with `input = "1 2\n" "3 Q 4\n" "5\n";`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When `input >> n;` encounters non-numeric input, it sets the `fail` flag. The code checks whether it is set (`if (input.fail())`), and if it is, ignores up to `numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()` characters, until it hits a newline `\n` character. Effectively, this means that the rest of the line on which the failure was encountered will be ignored.

Note that this will still read a number at the beginning of a line like `"25 asdasf"`. If the line is `"25 asdfasf 26"`, however, the 25 will be read, but then the failure occurs and the rest of the line is ignored, including the 26 at the end.

Comment: That helped me understand it a lot better. Thanks!