# C++ - How am I misusing ignore with istringstream?

Tags: c++, istringstream

I plan in main code to ask user to input phone number in form of (800) 555-1212, which will be sent to my PhoneNumber constructor then sent to setPhoneNumber for breaking it up, setting my private variables, and analysis for errors. Additionally, I wanted to write my setPhoneNumber code so it accounts for user errors in the original input. My PhoneNumber.h code is:

```
// PhoneNumber.h
#ifndef PHONENUMBER_H
#define PHONENUMBER_H

#include <string>

class PhoneNumber {
   private:
      short areaCode;
      short exchange;
      short line;
   public:
      PhoneNumber(std::string number);
      void setPhoneNumber(std::string number);
      void printPhoneNumber() const;
};
#endif
```

And here is my PhoneNumber.cpp code

```
// PhoneNumber.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cctype>
#include "PhoneNumber.h"

PhoneNumber::PhoneNumber(std::string number) {
   setPhoneNumber(number);
}

void PhoneNumber::setPhoneNumber(std::string number) {
   bool areaCodeDone = false;
   bool exchangeDone = false;
   int length = number.length();
   
   std::istringstream iss(number);
   for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      if (! areaCodeDone) {
         if (! std::isdigit(number[i])) {
            std::string str;
            iss >> std::ignore();
         }
         else {
            iss >> std::setw(3) >> areaCode;
            areaCodeDone = true;
         }
      }
      else if (! exchangeDone) {
         if (! std::isdigit(number[i])) {
            iss >> std::ignore();
         }
         else {
            iss >> std::setw(3) >> exchange;
            exchangeDone = true;
         }
      }
      else {
         if (! std::isdigit(number[i])) {
            iss >> std::ignore();
         }
         else {
            if (length - i < 4) {
               throw std::invalid_argument("Something wrong with phone number entry.");
            }
            else {
               iss >> std::setw(4) >> line;
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The errors I get are on my lines with std::ignore, but I don't know how I am using it incorrectly. Error from g++ compiler is:

> PhoneNumber.cpp:23:32: error: no match for call to ‘(const std::_Swallow_assign) ()’
>
> iss >> std::ignore();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::ignore()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/ignore) has a very different purpose than what you are hoping to accomplish. Instead of

```
iss >> std::ignore();
```

use

```
iss.ignore();
```

You can see the documentation of `std::istream::ignore()` and example usage at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore.

Answer (score 1):

[`std::ignore`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/ignore) doesn't do what you think it does: it is used for tuples.

Instead, what you looking for is actually called [`std::istream::ignore()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore). You would use it like this instead:

```
iss.ignore();
```

For more information on `std::istream::ignore()`, you can read [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14693106/10957435)